# Superscript isn't so super (aligns to baseline)

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

I was trying to use <sup>superscript</sup> to represent exponents in an answer, except they aren't rendering as superscript. Instead it looks the same as <sub>subscript</sub>.

The problem appears to be a `vertical-align: baseline;` in the CSS that is forcing it down.

**How I'd expect it to appear:**
[image: expected]

**How it currently appears for me in Chrome:**
[image: current]

Can we get the `<sup></sup>` to be superscript again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue was reported on multiple meta sites across the network and was corrected last week. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Thanks. The formatting looks good now.